# how to return click event by hardware menu button in android?

Tags: android, onclick, return, popupmenu

I have this code for show popup menu in click listener

**Code:**

```
    btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, btn_menu);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
                    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.one){

                    }else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.two){
                        try {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        }
                    }else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.three){
                        finish();   
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show(); //showing popup menu
        }
    }); //closing the setOnClickListener method

    //End PopUp Menu
```

Now I want when click on menu hardware button return this code again

**Code for menu click event :**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:        
           ????????
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

Please help me! thanks u.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of 2 default methods
onCreateOptionsMenu
onOptionsItemSelected
and an example.

Please go through the below example:

Add this to your activity class:
1. onCreateOptionsMenu: to inflate the menu layout. Design your menu accordingly in an xml file and inflate here.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

3. The layout file:
   game_menu.xml in this example will look like the following:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>         <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
>               android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
>               android:title="@string/new_game"
>               android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
>         <item android:id="@+id/help"
>               android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
>               android:title="@string/help" />
>     </menu>
> ```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html